# Click/Touch is not working for donut chart using achartengine

Tags: android, achartengine

Hi trying to develop donut chart using achartengine library in android. my requirement is when I click on any part of donut chart i need to highlight and display respective label in center. 
but when I am using onclick/ontouch listener irrespective of click its returning null.

```
mChartView2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
          if(v == mChartView2){
              Log.i("view", ""+((GraphicalView) v).getCurrentSeriesAndPoint());
          }
          Log.i("dfg", ""+((GraphicalView) v).getCurrentSeriesAndPoint());
        SeriesSelection seriesSelection = ((GraphicalView) v).getCurrentSeriesAndPoint();
        if (seriesSelection == null) {
          Toast.makeText(context1, "No chart element selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
              .show();
        }else {
            for (int i = 0; i < categorySeries.getCategoriesCount(); i++) {
                renderer.getSeriesRendererAt(i).setHighlighted(i == seriesSelection.getPointIndex());
              }
            mChartView2.repaint();
              Toast.makeText(
                 context1,
                  "Chart data point index " + seriesSelection.getPointIndex() + " selected"
                      + " point value=" + seriesSelection.getValue(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
          }
        });
```

Comment: mChartView2.getCurrentSeriesAndPoint() always returning null

Comment: That's only implemented for pie chart.

Comment: I had implemented for donut chart using achartengine

Comment: Only implemented for pie chart? So there's no way to get the point data for a line chart? Why the f*** wouldn't it mention that in the docs? That can't be right; the example line chart shows it being implemented